# How to add 60 months to current date in data stage jobs?

Tags: datastage

I am having a requirement to add 60 months to a date filed in DataStage application.

How can I implement 60 months addition to a date field?

Comment: It is data stage tool Marek.

Comment: I am using Info Sphere DataStage Designer to develope my jobs. I used DateOffsetByComponents(DSLink4.REV_DATE,0,60,0) to solve this. But with this I am facing an issue like: For example my data is 01-01-2015 and if I want add one month to it, by using the above function, it is giving 03-03-2015 as result. But I am expecting 02-28-2015 as result. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

this issue is there in datastage till FP8.x version. This issue is fixed in later versions. If you want to work in older versions, you need to install patch given by IBM to fix this or you need to write your own logic to get the date after adding months.